# Regex for channel subscription in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I want to match a pattern for kafka channel subscription which has changing pre-fix in python kafka consumer code.

Eg :

```
testsetup-test-topic
prodsetup-test-topic
```

I tried the following

```
c.subscribe(["*test-topic"])
But didnt get the message at the consumer.
```

Then

```
c.subscribe(["^*test-topic"])
But got the following error
```

> KafkaException: KafkaError{code=_INVALID_ARG,val=-186,str="Failed to
>   set subscription: Local: Invalid argument or configuration"} Can you
>   please help me in the above ?

```py
c.subscribe(["*test-topic"])
```

```py
c.subscribe(["^*test-topic"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested and verified the following works using Python 3.7.x and confluent-kafka 1.4.2.

```py
c.subscribe(['^.*-test-topic$'])
```